# Is using LinqToSql in a recursive method very bad for performance

Tags: c#, linq, performance, linq-to-sql

I have the following method which get all parents for a node using LinqToSql but I don't know how much it's bad for performance.

From NodeTable:

```
public partial class Node   
{
    public List<Node> GetAllParents(IEnumerable<Node> records)
    {
        if (this.ParentID == 0)
        {
            // Reach the parent, so create the instance of the collection and brake recursive.
            return new List<Node>();
        }

        var parent = records.First(p => p.ID == ParentID);

        // create a collection from one item to concat it with the all parents.
        IEnumerable<Node> lst = new Node[] { parent };

        lst = lst.Concat(parent.GetAllParents(records));

        return lst.ToList();
    }
}
```

Is it good !! or any idea to improve it !!

Thanks.

Comment: @Ani: No, It's in the partial class for the generated one which is created by LinqToSQL.

Comment: You shouldn't worry for performance unless you see that it takes really too much time at execution.  At this moment you can look where you loose most of the time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As such, above code is walking parent-child hierarchy in upward (parent's) direction. So in worst case, it would result in making n queries to database for hierarchy depth of n. I would suggest you to try deferred execution by changing method slightly such as

```
public IEnumerable<Node> GetAllParents(IEnumerable<Node> records)
{
        if (this.ParentID == 0)
        {
            // Reach the parent, so create the instance of the collection and brake recursive.
            return new List<Node>();
        }

        var parent = records.Where(p => p.ID == ParentID);
        var parents = parent.Concat(parent.GetAllParents(records));

        return parent;
}
```

I am not 100% sure if it would work but idea is to exploit expression trees/deferred execution so that multiple queries are fired within single database trip.

Yet another idea would be to write a stored proc/view that will returns all parent (look at CTE in sql server for the same).

**EDIT**: Used `Where` instead of `First` for finding parent in above code because First will certainly be evaluated immediately - (warning: still untested code)

Comment: Will my method make many round-trips on database? I'm not sure but I think No, because I pass all records to the method when I call it and It must get all the records before starting the recursive, isn't it? Or might I just must use `List<Node>` instead of `IEnumerable<Node>` !

Comment: @John-89, assumption here is that input has not been evaluated - so in such case, call to `First` method will force database query to fetch requested parent record. `ToList` would also force database query to fetch actual objects. You may pass all records (`List<Node>`) to your method and in that case there will be no database queries but performance would depend upon number of records. For example, say we want org reporting hierarchy (10-15 levels) for some employee among a large org of say 100000 employees, your method would entail fetching all 100000 employees instead of selecting 10-15.

Answer (score 3):

This will result in a query for every single parent node.

The best to approach this is too either write a stored procedure using CTE or if aforementioned not possible, do a breadth first search/query. The latter will require a query for every level, but will result in much less queries overall.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that there's much less you can do, this is - off the top of my head - the same but not recursive and possibly therefore a bit more efficient - but the issue is always going to be the query for the parent.

```
List<Node> parentList = new List<Node>();
Node current = this;
while (current.ParentID != 0)
{
    // current = this.Parent;
    current = records.First(r => r.ID == current.ParentID);
    parentList.Add(current)
}

return parentList;
```

Answer (score 0):

It depends on how big your hierarchy is likely to be. If you **know** that it is never going to need to recurse that many times is isnt a problem, however it maybe quicker to just load the entire table into memory rather than sending multiple calls to the db.